# How to determine which method is generating the most garbage

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, benchmarking, heap-memory

I have three objects:

```
ClassA classA = new ClassA();
ClassA classB = new ClassA();
ClassA classC = new ClassA();
```

Each of these objects has a `public void` called `run` which does something and is called in the following way:

```
   classA.run();                                                                             
   classB.run();                                                                             
   classC.run();
```

Within each loop iteration, a particular amount of garbage is generated by each `run` call.

How do I accurately determine the amount of generated garbage by each `run`?

Comment: You have no control over garbage collection. finalize(), runFinalizersOnExit() etc are not guaranteed to run.. Why not leave the finer details to the JVM?

Comment: I do have control of garbage collection in one sense - I can see what makes the most garbage then reduce the garbage made.This is my objective,

Comment: but WHY is that your objective? This smells suspiciously like premature optimization.

Comment: @Gimby For a real time system where GC stop the world is undesired ....

Comment: Limiting the amount of garbage simply delays the GC but it's going to happen eventually and you cannot be sure when.  To solve the problem you should look at real-time JVM like Zing - http://www.azulsystems.com/products/zing/virtual-machine - which uses their C4 Continuously Concurrent Compacting Collector that avoids GC pauses altogether.

Comment: @user2763361: agreed with that -very specific- case, so the next time you may just want to explain up front what the context is.

Answer (score 3):

Normally (if you can say that for OP's use case), you use profilers/logging to estimate allocation pressure. JRockit Mission Control (works with JDK 7u40!), for instance, can dump the current allocation rate. Doing `run` continuously, one might get the estimate what is the allocation rate per `run` call. Make sure you measure `run` call rate rigorously, because at this point you are dealing with benchmarks. Take [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) for example.

This is boring, however. For something completely different, I have a tricky (but fun!) suggestion. Since in most modern VMs, HotSpot included, new objects are allocated linearly in thread-local allocation buffers (TLAB), it may be possible to get an address mark, execute `run()`, then get another address mark, subtract both marks, and get the amount of space wasted in TLAB during the call.

In fact, in `jol`, we have [the funny example doing almost exactly this thing](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jol/file/4aa90b3ecb20/jol-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jol/samples/JOLSample_17_Allocation.java).

Answer (score 2):

There is a little know JVM option -Xaprof that reports global allocation totals for each class. We have created an in-house open-source "aprof" tool that reports allocation rates in each method for each class: https://code.devexperts.com/display/AProf/

It performs object allocation tracking by doing on-the-fly byte code modification and attempts to balance performance impact with depth and precision of its reports. It does significantly increase application startup time, but has a negligible runtime performance impact, so that we can use it in production on our server-side components.

Aprof precisely collects all "new" operation in the code, but does not collect the full stack-trace for each allocation. It tracks a "location" of each allocation operation (class name and method name), while providing a way to attribute an allocation of char[] in, for example, StringBuilder method, to the actual application code that had invoked the corresponding StringBuilder method. It comes with a set of sensible defaults for all popular java.lang and java.util classes that do allocate memory inside of them, so that you can see your actual application classes as an ultimate location source of those allocations.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the built-in profiler `VisualVM` to see the nitty gritty.

You can find it inside your JDK/bin folder under the name `jvisualvm.exe` or something like that.

Comment: How do I use VisualVM for this task?

Comment: Once you launch it, just choose the java process your application is running under from the list on the left (You'll probably will have to look up its PID through task manager or what have you), open that up and you should see a various tabs like Monitoring/Threads/Sampler/Profiler, GC activity and Heap size in Monitoring will show you an overall view on things you are probably interested in but you should use either the sampler or profiler (probably profiler to be more accurate) to see which method/classes are using what amounts of memory for the duration of what CPU time.

Answer (score 0):

```
double[] heapFreeSizez = new double[5];
for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i) {
    heapFreeSizez[i] = 0;
}

heapFreeSizez[0] = (double) Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/1000000.0;
classA.run(); heapFreeSizez[1] = (double) Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/1000000.0;
classB.run(); heapFreeSizez[2] = (double) Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/1000000.0;
classC.run(); heapFreeSizez[3] = (double) Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/1000000.0;
classD.run(); heapFreeSizez[4] = (double) Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/1000000.0;

for(int i = 1 ; i < 5 ; ++i) {
    if(heapFreeSizez[i] - heapFreeSizez[i-1] < 0) {

        System.out.println(i + "_" + "HELP!"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [ThreadMXBean#getThreadAllocatedBytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9810661/1261287)?
It tells you the amount of allocated memory by a particular thread.
All you need to do is just measure the difference (and account for some 8-16 bytes garbage produced by `getThreadAllocatedBytes` itself)